# Encrypting csv and Json files in Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, csv, encryption

I have a python code that reds and writes to json and csv files. I want to secure the information contained within the files. Is there a way I could encrypt `json` and `csv` files so that the data stored in them would only be readable by the python code only?

Comment: No. Decryption will work with any software that has the key, You can't limit it to a single programming language. If that's okay, there are still a thousand ways to encrypt things. You need to research this instead of taking some random answer (among many optoins) here.